# Responsive Websites

Tags: html, mobile, responsiveness

I have managed to build a "decent" website (for a Beginner, in my opinion). And, the layout is something like this :

[image]

One thing i realised, that it's horribly messy when I open it with a phone :

[image]

So, i decided to google for "Responsive Website" and there's quite many stuff to do, so i figure in the meantime, when people access my website using phones, it'll be just like they open it with pc's browser, they might have to zoom out a bit, so they will see this when they access my website :

[image]

So, what should i add in my code lines to make my layout 'locked' in every screen size ? (Sorry, if i'm not being clear)

PS : What i'm trying to achieve something like in this [website](http://www.lionstar.co.id/) (Notice how the layout isn't affected when we zoom in)

Comment: please provide a code or a jsfiddle of what you've got so far or what have you tried. It will be easier for us to help you with your problem.

Comment: show your html and css code, also did you add media queries to your css? http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/JKdOaj

Comment: um, but many of my website elements is local, but i have deployed, my website, maybe you can kindly check here [link](http://polaris-orionis.com/)

Comment: i didnt use any media queries, since im not quite familiar with it...

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to create your custom responsive class or you only want to make your site responsive because you don't have enough experience. If you try the first, remember not reinvent the wheel, use bootstrap

Comment: @ReneLimon I know im very young to this website thing, all I want for this time is just so that users using phone will see the exact same layout as users from web browser. They just have to zoom out...

Answer (score 0):

To let website on mobile browsers as it is on pc browsers remove meta tag with

> name="viewport"

and dont use media query in css

Comment: can you please explain more ? i'm very new to this vast world of coding

Comment: @Ricky Gani please refer to the link for info on how this tag work and how will it lock or unlock resizing of your website http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

Nice work on the website. 
To do something about mobile responsiveness you can do the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Next thing would be to add either bootstrap or media queries.
To save space people use media queries and to divide the sections so that a site looks different on different devices, people use bootstrap classes.

Examples can be looked up on w3schools.

Comment: im sorry if im being very ignorant here, But what does this meta tag actually do? I read on w3school that it's a quick fix for responsiveness. I have put in the meta tag, but when i zoomed in (using web browser), it's still the same as picture #3

Comment: This meta tag helps in responsiveness of any website.
If you're still having problems then I prefer you download bootstrap from getboostrap.com

Then you can add classes like <div class="row"> and can divide content.

Comment: I actually use some bootstrap in this website, i think i'm not using it right... please see the edit in the original post to see what i mean i asked (Sorry if my question is too confusing)

Comment: I got the answer. ( http://polaris-orionis.com/index.html ) this website is currently responsive and works fine in phones and tablets. But its not full width. To do that  remove all the <div> tags and add just one tag <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1"> In this tag add your carousel. then look if the carousel works fine.

Comment: thanks for your time, but what do you mean by remove all div tags ? wouldn't it mess up all my css styling? (i used div tags as wrappers)

Comment: Ricky, It's pretty much messed up already.
I told you to experiment this on only your carousel. If it works fine with mobile view, you can add all the <div> tags inside it. 
Please let me know if it works fine, if it does I'll tell you what to do next